# Visual Studio SQL Server Project TargetFrameworkVersion

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I've just upgraded Visual Studio 2022 to v17.8 which includes .Net8.

As an experiment I created a SQL Server Project.

Looking at the .sqlproj file it shows `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.7.2</TargetFrameworkVersion>`.

There's no option to seleect a .Net version when creating a SQL project in Visual Studio so how is TargetFrameworkVersion set?

What is it's significance in a visual studio sql project?

If I were to alter it to say `<TargetFrameworkVersion>net8.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` what would the effect be?

Thanks